# Why can't I get the index of a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Why can't I get the index of `hdjs` inside `jdks`?  `jdks` is a jQuery object with all `id^=name` blocks having errors in them. `hdjs` is a block with an ID starting by "name" which has an error in it.

So why am I getting `-1` when console.logging the index?

```js
function $errorObjectFunction() {
        return $("div[id^=name]").map(function() {
            if ($(this).find(":first-child").hasClass("error") == true || $(this).find(".field_error").length > 0)    {
                return $(this)
            }
        });
    }
var $self = $("#self");
var jdks = $errorObjectFunction();
var hdjs = $self.parent().parent().parent();
console.log("index: " + jdks.index(hdjs));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name1">
    <div class="fourteen wide field error">
        <input id="OfficeName1"/>
        <div class="dropdown"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="name2">
    <div class="fourteen wide field">
        <input id="OfficeName2"/>
        <div class="dropdown field_error"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="name3">
    <div class="fourteen wide field error">
        <input id="OfficeName3"/>
        <div class="dropdown field_error"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="name4">
    <div class="fourteen wide field error">
        <input id="OfficeName4"/>
        <div class="dropdown field_error">
            <input id="self"/> 
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
<div id="name5">
    <div class="fourteen wide field">
        <input id="OfficeName5"/>
        <div class="dropdown"></div>     
    </div>
</div>
<div id="name6">
    <div class="fourteen wide field error">
        <input id="OfficeName6"/>
        <div class="dropdown field_error"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `map()` is giving you want you want.

Since you want to filter element from an array it's easier to use `filter()` instead of `map()`.

```
function $errorObjectFunction() {
    return $("div[id^=name]").filter(function() {
        return ($(this).find(":first-child").hasClass("error") == true  || $(this).find(".field_error").length > 0)
    });
}
var $self = $("#self");
var jdks = $errorObjectFunction();
var hdjs = $self.parent().parent().parent();
console.log("index: " + jdks.index(hdjs));

// logs "index: 3"
```

The problem you are having with map, is that returning `$(this)` is making your array a list of query objects rather than dom elements. I think the `filter()` approach is much nicer, but if you need to use `map()` for some reason use: `return this` instead to return the actual dom element.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  I didn't realize that `.map()` was not returning the same thing as `.filter()`.  I kept console.logging the variables, and it didn't appear as they were different. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't either until I looked at the console. Map is returning `[n,n,n]` filter is returning `[<div>, <div>, etc]`

Comment: Why would you `return $(this).get()` instead of just `return this`? Doing so would cause errors, as [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2) without an argument returns an Array of elements, not a single element. This would cause just as much corruption of the jQuery Object being returned as `return $(this)`.

Comment: Overall, this could be more clearly stated by explaining that the OP was corrupting the jQuery Object returned by `$errorObjectFunction` by using `map` to change the jQuery Object's list of elements into a list of jQuery Objects (and undefined, as the `map` function is not guaranteed to return a value). This, of course, confused jQuery when the OP later attempted to use `.index()` on what was no longer a conforming jQuery Object, but which still had the jQuery prototype.

Answer (score 4):

#### Return `this` not `$(this)`

The most obvious problem is that you're returning `$(this)` in the map callback instead of `this`. `$(this)` is a problem (pardon the pun) because the `jQuery#index` call that later operates on the returned array is looking for an Element object, not a jQuery object.

Return `this` not `$(this)`:

```
function $errorObjectFunction() {
    return $("div[id^=name]").map(function() {
        if ($(this).find(":first-child").hasClass("error") == true || 
            $(this).find(".field_error").length > 0) {
            return this;
        }
    });
}
```

```js
var outers = $(".outer");
(function() {
  var others = outers.map(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.find(':first-child').hasClass('other') ||
        $el.find('.inner-other').length) {
      return $el;
    }
  });
  // Checks if each element is instance of jQuery
  console.log(Array.from(others.map((i, e) => e instanceof jQuery)));
  // [ true, true, true ] 
  // This means that all of the elements are jQuery objects
})();
(function() {
  var others = outers.map(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.find(':first-child').hasClass('other') ||
        $el.find('.inner-other').length) {
      return this;
    }
  });
  // Checks if each element is instance of Element
  console.log(Array.from(others.map((i, e) => e instanceof Element)));
  // [ true, true, true ] 
  // This means that all of the elements are Element objects
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="outer-1"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-2"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-3"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-4"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
```

---

#### Use `filter` not `map`

The next problem is that you're using [`jQuery#map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to filter a list of elements where using [`jQuery#filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) would be *more* appropriate (more on that below).

Use `filter` not `map`:

```
function $errorObjectFunction() {
    return $("div[id^=name]").filter(function() {
        if ($(this).find(":first-child").hasClass("error") || 
            $(this).find(".field_error").length) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

```js
var outers = $(".outer");
var others = outers.filter(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    return ($el.find(':first-child').hasClass('other') ||
            $el.find('.inner-other').length);
});
console.log(Array.from(others.map((i, e) => e instanceof Element)));
// [ true, true, true ]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="outer-1"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-2"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-3"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-4"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
```

---

#### Combine the selectors

One further optimization in this direction would be to combine the selectors:

```
function $errorObjectFunction() {
    return $("div[id^=name]").filter(function(el) {
        return $(el).find(":first-child.error, .field_error").length;
    });
}
```

```js
var outers = $(".outer");
var others = outers.filter(function(el) {
    return $(el).find(':first-child.other, .inner-other').length;
});
console.log(Array.from(others.map((i, e) => e instanceof Element)));
// [ true, true, true ]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="outer-1"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-2"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-3"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-4"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
```

---

#### Just use the `:has(selector)` selector

That said, you could simply use the [jQuery `:has(selector)` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).
This would provide the same result as your above filter in less steps, and would allow jQuery to optimize the selection.

Use the `:has(selector)` selector like so:

```
function $errorObjectFunction() {
    return $('div[id^=name]:has(:first-child.error, .field_error)');
}
```

```js
var others = $(".outer:has(:first-child.other, .inner-other)");
console.log(Array.from(others.map((i, e) => e instanceof Element)));
// [ true, true, true ]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="outer-1"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-2"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-3"><div class="inner other">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
<div class="outer" id="outer-4"><div class="inner">
  <div class="text"></div><div class="inner-other"></div>
</div></div>
```

---

I've changed a few things in the hidden snippets to make it easier to read. You can check out [this JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ruzakucoli/1/edit?html,js,output) to see all of these examples in action together.

---

#### Further reading

If you've missed any of the links above, I've collected them down here for you:

- [`jQuery#map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`jQuery#filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- [jQuery `:has(selector)` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)
- [Examples in action](http://jsbin.com/ruzakucoli/1/edit?html,js,output)